# Instruments Time Profiler

Tags: xcode, xcode-instruments

i'm trying to run Time Profiler in Instruments and when it fires off I do not see anything in the Call Tree. Anyone see this before?

[image]

Comment: Does it have anything to do with you having `UICatalog` selected under *targets*? If you press "Stop", you should see something with that (like Symbols, etc). If you attach to your process you care about, you should see the data.

Comment: Are you opening Instruments manually or are you having Xcode to open it using the 'Profile' button?

Answer (score 0):

If your program is quite small, you have to stop record then the data appears.